# SQL Update From Another Table with Where

Tags: sql, sql-server

Hoping someone can help!

I'm trying to update a SQL Server table with data from another that requires a where clause so I only update rows related to a specific ID in that table. I've created the below (and many other variations) but I always get this error:

> Msg 8624, Level 16, State 21, Procedure tContactPhone_INSUPD, Line 66 [Batch Start Line 13]
> Internal Query Processor Error: The query processor could not produce a query plan. For more information, contact Customer Support Services.

This is my update query. If you can help me understand what I'm doing wrong it will help me tearing what little hair I have left out!

```
UPDATE table1 
SET column2 = table2.column2
FROM table1 
INNER JOIN table2 ON table1.column1 = table2.column1
WHERE table1.column3 = '27';
```

[image: Example of data tables in this link]

Comment: What version of SQL Server are you using? What does `PRINT @@VERSION;` return? Is that really your query? That would be a very simple query for SQL Server to generate a execution for.

Comment: Microsoft SQL Server 2014 (SP3-CU-GDR) (KB4535288) - 12.0.6372.1 (X64)

Comment: that is related to that database, can you check its compatibility model?

Comment: compatibility level is 120

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
UPDATE table1
   SET column2 = (SELECT column2 FROM table2 WHERE table2.column1=table1.column1)
  FROM table1 
 WHERE table1.column3 = '27';
```

Comment: I would, personally, suggest that the RDBMS is likely something to have an easier time with a `JOIN`. Putting the subquery in the `SELECT` *can* sometimes cause the data engine to run the subquery once for each row, rather than once for the entire dataset. (I would, however, hope it does not here.)

Comment: Thanks, Piyush - tried you query but I get the same result